# Put small clickable boxes on image - html

Tags: html, css

I have an image like this

[image]

I want to put small clickable boxes on it, like this

[image]

Does anybody have any idea how to do this using HTML/CSS?

**Edit**: Thanks to @BCollingwood, his answer with boxes property as absolute worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all images to a container div then position them relative to each other using CSS:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image_1" /> // the background
  <img class="image_2" /> // the clickable square
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
      position: relative;
    }

.image_2 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px;
      top: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!!! Just wanted to ask you one thing, that it is not responsive. Can it be ?

Comment: Awesome! glad I could help. A simple way would be to use a "onClick" describe here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onclick2 change "style.color" to src = "path to your different colored image"

Answer (score 0):

you have to use svg. it is not wise to use anything other than svg to make certain part of image clickable.

[https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp]